# How to set item level audience targeting for a Links List?

Tags: 2007, audiences, list-view-web-part

I created a Link List where each item has a specific target audience from the Active Directory group assigned. I added this link list on a page as a web part.

I am trying to get the user to ONLY be able to see the items on the list to which they have access to from the target audience field.

I am using SharePoint 2007 Server Standard Edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applied what is stated in this link and worked, even with target audience.

http://www.sharepoint-tips.com/2007/01/teach-content-query-web-part-how-to.html

Answer (score 3):

The only out-of-box WebPart that supports audience filtering by content item is the Content Query Web Part. It is part of the Publishing Infrastructure Site Collection feature and requires SharePoint Server edition (not included with Foundation).

Add a CQWP to your page, wire it up to your linked list, and then click the checkbox to enable Audience filtering.

[image]

Comment: Sadly true. I think the only other way to do this is by using item-level permissions which solves the wrong problem.

Comment: I tried creating a Content Query Editor Web Part but the results came up empty. I tried playing with item level permissions, but isn't that for created items on a list so it can display only to the person who created it? We have Sharepoint 2007 Server Standard.

Comment: So you added a CQWP to a page, and set it up and there were no results? If you turn off Audience filtering, do results show up? First make sure you have the query to retrieve items itself working. Then enabled audience filtering and go from there. The feature works, I have used it many times. You may need to take a look at your Audiences to make sure they have been compiled, and that the right test users are in the audience membership when you view them.

Comment: I think the problem lies in the presentation. I did turn off target audience. I get returned a link that displays (Blank) which points to the display format  of the link list entry

Comment: CQWP Properties:
List Type: Links
Content Type: <All Content Types>

Presentation
Group style: Default
Item style: Title only

Remember this is callink a LINK List

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the audience is a misleading concept, it does not filter the view unless filtered at library list view.

Comment: I have tried using the target audience in the link list settings and works fine. But creating a new link list for each link isn't very neat...